# ¿Como crear un metodo en el MainApp desde estos metodos prepared statement de otra clase?

Tags: java, poo, jdbc, prepared-statements

Tengo dos metodos en una clase para guardar usuarios en una base de datos de tipo prepared statement, como puedo crear una clase en el Main que use el prepared statement de forma adecuada, para poder introducir usuarios en mi base de datos? Soy nueva en esto de usar prepared statement y en las jdbc en general y nose muy bien como guiarme usando poo.

```
public void saveAll(User[] users){

    for (User user: users) {
        System.out.println("Save");
        save(user);
    }

    encryptAll();

    try {

        connection.close();

    } catch (SQLException e){

        e.getMessage();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean save(User user){


    String insert = "INSERT INTO User (firstname, lastName, email, phoneNumber, roles, " +
            "password, active, locale, idEnterprise, birthday) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insert);

        preparedStatement.setString(1,user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,user.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3,user.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setString(4,user.getPhoneNumber());
        preparedStatement.setString(5,user.getRoles());
        preparedStatement.setString(6,user.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setInt(7,user.getActive());
        preparedStatement.setString(8,user.getLocale());
        preparedStatement.setInt(9,user.getIdEnterprise());
        preparedStatement.setObject(10,user.getBirthday());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    }catch (SQLException ex){

        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En la POO, cada clase es un modelo con el que hacer objetos. Con todas las propiedades y características de esos objetos. No las definiciones, sino las propiedades sin definir. Es en la construcción del objeto donde se definen.

Por ejemplo, la clase linterna puede tener la propiedad numero_pilas_necesarias. Es en el momento de construir el objeto linterna cuando se le da valor a esta propiedad, pero todos los objetos de esta clase deben tener esta propiedad. Al igual que pueden tener otra propiedad distinta llamada numero_pilas_introducidas.

Cuando un objeto de otra clase tiene que acceder a alguna de las propiedades del objeto creado en otra clase distinta, esta otra clase distinta tendrá su getter, para poder acceder a esa propiedad. Esas propiedades son definidas como propiedades de clase, ya que no son variables/constantes necesarias sólo por 1 método, como podría ser la variable "encendida" dentro del método encender(). Sino que son propiedades de la propia clase, por eso se definen en la clase, no dentro de ningún método.

De esta forma, un objeto perteneciente a la clase Personal_Mantenimiento podrá acceder al método encender(). Como el método encender ejecuta un catch que emite un JOPtionPane que indica que no hay pilas, el objeto Personal_Mantenimiento accederá a las 2 propiedades numero_pilas_necesarias y numero_pilas_introducidas para saber cuantas pilas le hacen falta. Y lo hará por medio de los métodos getter de la clase linterna.

Es importante entender el paradigma de programación POO, para poder crear bien nuestras clases, y por ejemplo, no acabar creando un método "tirar caña de cerveza" o una propiedad n_barriles_cerveza dentro de una clase linterna. Por más oscuro que esté la zona donde uno coloca el barril en un bar y necesite una linterna para colocar el barril, una linterna es una linterna, y una barra de bar es una barra de bar.

También es importante saber que no se debe acceder a las variables de clase directamente. Igual que el personal de mantenimiento no accede a los cables del interior de la linterna para encenderla y apagarla, sino que accede al método interruptor. Es el método interruptor el que accede a las propiedades de clase, y cambia la variable booleana de clase "encendida". Por eso la encapsulación de las propiedades o variables de clase. Para acceder a ellas a través de sus setters y getters, no directamente.

Resumiendo y aplicando a tu pregunta:

Si es lógico que tu clase tenga la propiedad PreparedStatement, crea la variable preparedStatement fuera de todos los métodos, pero dentro de la clase, y como private. Y después crea un getter para acceder a ella.

Si no es lógico que tu clase tenga esa propiedad, quizás sería buena idea crear una clase dedicada sólo a las conexione, genérica para cualquier conexión pero que admita como parámetros las peculiaridades de cada conexión.